# Trying to put output of grep command into a bash array

Tags: bash, grep, array

If I run the following grep command I get the output I am expecting:

```
$ grep -o -E '/ |:|\\|<|>|\*|\?|\"| $' <<< '/home/ttwaro/temp/Test/This is a Test: Testing Number 1?/This is Test: Testing Number 1?.eng.srt'
:
?
:
?
```

But when I attempt to put the output into an array I get the character 'C' instead of the question mark '?'. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ array=()
$ array+=($(grep -o -E '/ |:|\\|<|>|\*|\?|\"| $' <<< '/home/ttwaro/temp/Test/This is a Test: Testing Number 1?/This is Test: Testing Number 1?.eng.srt'))
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
:
C
:
C
```

Comment: ... you have a file named `C` in the current directory, that is matched by the unquoted `?` glob perhaps?

Comment: When I run this code, I get `?` on the first line then `:` and then `?`; I don't get the first ':", but no 'C's either.

Comment: @frabjous try again in a directory with at least one file or subdir whose name is a single character. The OP happens to have a file/dir named `C` which is why they see `C`.

Comment: I see. The middle command is basically `array+=(? : ?)` which is globbing to the single character file. The reason I don't get the first `:` is that the OP is using a different string after the `<<<` in the two examples, which is confusing.

Comment: @frabjous exactly. And yes, it is indeed confusing, it took me a while to spot it while writing my answer too!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I copied and pasted the wrong line in the second grep. Thanks for spotting that. The second grep was suppose to be exactly like the first grep.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this is happening is because you have a file or subdirectory named `C` in the directory where you are running the command and so the glob `?` is expanded to match it. To illustrate with a simpler example:

```
$ ls -la
total 92
drwxr-xr-x   2 terdon terdon 16384 Mar 26 18:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 170 terdon terdon 73728 Mar 26 13:57 ..

$ array=( $( printf '?\n' ) )
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
?
```

Now, I create a file named `C` and try again:

```
$ touch C
$ array=( $( printf '?\n' ) )
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
C
```

This is down to the order of operations. When you run `array=( $( printf '?\n' ) )`, what happens, in order, is:

1. The `printf '?\n'` is executed and returns a `?`.
2. The *unquoted* `?` is expanded by the shell to any matching file names, in this case one called `C`.
3. The expanded glob, the `C`, is stored as element `0` of the array `array`.

To avoid this, you need to quote the array assignment so that any globbing characters are protected from the shell:

```
$ array=( "$( printf '?\n' )" )
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
?
```

Or, with your original example:

```
$ array=( "$(grep -o -E '/ |:|\\|<|>|\*|\?|\"| $' <<< '/home/ttwaro/temp/Test/This is a Test: Testing Number 1?/This is Test: Testing Number 1?.eng.srt')" )
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
:
?
:
?
```

However, because it is quoted, the entire result is presented as a single string and so the array will only have one element:

```
$ for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do 
    printf 'element %s is %s\n' "$i" "${array[i]}"; 
done
element 0 is :
?
:
?
```

To get each result as a separate element in the array, you need to do something like this as suggested by [Gordon Davisson](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6511/gordon-davisson) in the comments:

```
$ readarray -t array < <(grep -o -E '/ |:|\\|<|>|\*|\?|\"| $' <<< '/home/ttwaro/temp/Test/This is a Test: Testing Number 1?/This is Test: Testing Number 1?.eng.srt')

$ for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do 
    printf 'element %s is %s\n' "$i" "${array[i]}"; 
done
element 0 is :
element 1 is ?
element 2 is :
element 3 is ?
```

This will circumvent the need for quoting since the output of `grep` is never seen by the shell.

Finally, the reason you got two `C`s in your result is because each of the `?` was expanded to a `C` when it was stored in the array:

```
$ array=( ? ? ? )
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
C
C
C
```

Comment: The version with double-quotes creates an array with just a single element (which contains all of the matches, separated by newline characters). To get each match in a separate element, use `readarray -t array < <(grep ...)`

Comment: @terdon: Thank you for the great explanation. i now get the expected result by enclosing the array with quotes in the print statement but I still don't understand why the '?" is replaced by a "C". The is no file with the name "C"

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Thanks, that was going to be my next question. My reason for doing this is to find all the files names that contain invalid windows characters. I not only print the invalid file name but accumulate the invalid characters and finally sort them with the --unique parameter to quickly see which characters are invalid.

Comment: @GordonDavisson duh, of course! Thanks, answer edited.

Comment: @Tommy pelase see updated answer which includes Gordon's fix. That said, there must be a file or directory or something named `C`, try running your original command in a new, empty directory, do you still get the `C`?